# How to unit test conditional window width with QUnit / Chutzpah

Tags: javascript, qunit, chutzpah

```
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    // do stuff
} else if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do stuff
}
```

Within the test, doing a `console.log($(window).width());` outputs 400, so if < 500 is covered.
Unfortunately not all the JS can be converted to SASS/CSS.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Chutzpah, but I see that it uses Phantomjs for the browser environment. Phantom provides an interface for setting the [viewport size](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html), but I don't know how you would set that in Chutzpah.